# I'm Looking for a picture of a 5 masted sailing ship called Capitan Hilgendorf. (Barquentine)?

Tags: world-war-two

The Germans trained sailors and Navy Infantrymen on this ship. I have looked at several sites with numerous information and listings. Can anyone steer me in the right direction? I know that most all of Germany's ships were dispersed among the allies for reparation. I also am aware that many of the ships were re-named.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

I found a picture, a newspaper article and a book excerpt about this ship. According to the book the ship was a 5 mast schooner, built in 1918 in Vancouver. It was acquired by German Ministry of Transport in 1939. In 1939 it was named "Kapitän Hilgendorf" (after [Robert Hilgendorf](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Hilgendorf)). It seems that in 1939 it was only used as stationary school for sailors.

[Picture](https://www.weitze.net/militaria/08/Pressefoto_Die_neue_Schiffsjungenschule_Kapitaen_Hilgendorf_in_Dienst_gestellt__165108.html)

[Newspaper article](http://digiview.gbv.de/viewer/image/72223831276/1378/#head)

[Book excerpt](https://books.google.de/books?id=mbcbCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&lpg=PT41&dq=schiffsjungenschule+hamburg+hilgendorf&source=bl&ots=80fHgU9eVM&sig=J-I1aw8SggpRdY36lzFo5cZ4Wo8&hl=de&sa=X&ei=WqhlVYrEBMiQsAGy2oDAAQ&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=schiffsjungenschule%20hamburg%20hilgendorf&f=false)

Comment: Thank you for the great help locating the photo of the Capitaan Hilgendorf. You have made an old German sailor very happy. He server aboard this ship at age 14. As soon as I can figure out how this site works I'll follow you.